# How to prevent automatic text size adjustment after screen orientation change on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I am building a Safari extension for iPadOS. When the screen orientation changes, the text size on my page changes substantially.

WebKit no longer honors the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` CSS property on iPads (see [this change to webkit](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/261940/webkit)). If I was using a native app with a webview, I could just use [preferredContentMode property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebpagepreferences/3194426-preferredcontentmode).